# extending the abstractuser model for two different user types (customer,vendor)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

models.py

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
 from django.db import models
 from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


 class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
"""Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

def _create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
    return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

    if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
    if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

    return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)




 class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
     is_customer = models.BooleanField('customer status', default=False)
     is_vendor = models.BooleanField('vendor status', default=False)


 class Customer(models.Model):
     customeruser = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
      primary_key=True)
     username = None
     email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
     firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      mobileno = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()


 class Vendor(models.Model):
     vendoruser = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
     username = None
     email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
     firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     mobileno = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

1. I am using the email field as main field instead of the username field to signup and login. also, in admin.py i used email as the main field. While attempting makemigrations showing error (django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (mobileno) specified for CustomUser)Is it the right way to approach?
2. can i use django default auth login,logout,password-reset functionalities for both of these user types?

admin.py

```
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
 from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
 from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


 class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
     """Define admin model for custom User model with no username 
 field."""
     fieldsets = (
         (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
         (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 
 'mobileno')}),
         (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 
 'is_superuser',
                                   'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
         (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 
 'date_joined')}),
     )
     add_fieldsets = (
         (None, {
             'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email','first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 
 'password2','mobileno'),
         }),
     )
     list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name','mobileno', 
 'is_staff')
     search_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'mobileno')
     ordering = ('email',)


 admin.site.register(get_user_model(), CustomUserAdmin)
```

forms.py

```
 from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
 from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm



 class UserAdminCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
     """
     A Custom form for creating new users.
     """

     class Meta:
         model = get_user_model()
         fields = ['email','first_name','last_name','mobileno']



 class VendorAdminCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

     class Meta:
         model = get_user_model()
         fields = ['email','first_name','last_name','mobileno']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migration error... I would say you have `mobileno` somewhere in `admin.py` On CustomUser ModelAdmin class.

About User model. What you actually did is that you have still one user model(I think Django's auth doesn't support more) with some extra data for Customers and Vendors. So `USERNAME_FIELD`, `REQUIRED_FIELDS` etc. should be just on `CustomUser` class and only fields specified for customers and vendors should be on these models.

so your models should look something like this:

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
    mobileno = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def is_customer(self):
        return hasattr(self, "customer")

    def is_vendor(self):
        return hasattr(self, "vendor")



class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    primary_key=True)
    customer_number = models.CharField(max_length=32)  # just some customer specific field
    

class Vendor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    vendor_number = models.CharField(max_length=32)  # just some vendor specific field
```

And you can add `create_customer` and `create_vendor` methods to manager:

```py
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    def _create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
    
    def create_customer(self, email, password=None, customer_number, **extra_fields):
        user = self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
        Customer.objects.create(user=user, customer_number=customer_number)
        return user
    
    def create_vendor(self, email, password=None, vendor_number, **extra_fields):
        user = self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
        Vendor.objects.create(user=user, vendor_number=vendor_number)
        return user
```

You can read about it in Django's docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: Thanks, for the help. If my need is, Vendor signup is having so many specific fields.(aadhar no,pan no, store name, brand name, acct no, ifsc code,....). can I add to create_vendor to custommanager? Can't I use django-auth login,logout,.. for customer and vendor?

Comment: Yes, you can use Django auth. Django's auth will use `CustomUser` for login where the email and password is stored. All types of user will have `CustomUser` record with email and password. In short all users will have record in table `CustomUser` and then related record in `Vendor` or(and) `Customer` tables depending on type. Yes you can add `create_vendor` to Manager as I did in example aboce.

Comment: sorry for again and again asking. above I mention admin.py, forms.py. while adding methods (create_vendor,customer_vendor)  shows- Non-default argument follows default argument. I store this model in one app(customer). As you said all the user details(customer,vendor) are stored in one user model under customer app. how can I store user model under two different apps (customer, vendor)?

Comment: You can have only one user model(table with email, password and all fields that all users share). But you can use tables as Customer, Vendor etc to extend it. It means every customer or vender has related record in users table. In short every customer is also user but every user doesn't have to be customer nor vendor. When you creating customer or vendor you have basically create two records. `CustomerUser` first and and `Customer` where you set link to created user.

Comment: Maybe start with this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/ it's what you need. In your case you have 2 one-to-one relations. Between `CustomUser` and `Customer` and the second is between `CustomUser` and `Vendor`

Comment: you gave me great help. I understand the things. I will be concentrating on this.